# Explicit conversion from std::string object to char* without using any of std::string member functions

Tags: c++, string

This question is not about any problem but more of a question to deeply understand the memory layout of `std::string`.

I did some experiments and realized that it is possible to explicitly convert `std::string` to `char*` and successfully retrieve the "string" stored in a `std::string` object. The question is, how is it possible when the starting address of a `std::string` object is different from the address returned by the `std::string::c_str()` method?

Recently, I came across this explicit conversion from a `std::string` object to `char*`. Initially, I thought this kind of conversion doesn't work with `std::string`, but I am surprised to know that it works.

```cpp
int main()
{
    std::string TestString = "Testing";

    void * pPointerToStringObject = (void *)&TestString;
    char * pExplicitlyConvertedString = *((char **)pPointerToStringObject);

    printf("Pointer to the string object : %p\n", pPointerToStringObject);
    printf("Pointer returned by c_str()  : %p\n\n", TestString.c_str());

    printf("\"String\" retrieved by explicit conversion of string object : \"%s\"\n", pExplicitlyConvertedString);
}
```

Output :

```
Pointer to the string object : 0x7ffd84d3f4a0
Pointer returned by c_str()  : 0x7ffd84d3f4b0

"String" retrieved by explicit conversion of string object : "Testing"
```

Comment: The memory layout of `std::string` is not specified.

Comment: *"I am surprised to know that it works"* You are being mislead. It's undefined behavior so it *might* work *sometimes*. It looks like it happens that, for you, with your platform, with that compiler and standard library implementation, the pointer to the memory buffer coincides with the address of the string. Edit : I hadn't noticed the pointers are different. It may just be that you have a bunch of non-printable data before the actual character date.

Comment: Even if you have in your current implementation the string as first element inside std::string, you will always fail if your string is longer as the "short string optimization"  size. Try it out by making your test string longer as SSO, typically 16 bytes.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux : "the pointer to the memory buffer coincides with the address of the string" - In fact it does not. Please refer to the **Output** in question.

Comment: @Gavi Please reread the comment, it seems you didn't catch the edit (it's labeled).

Comment: DO NOT do this in production code.  Noodling around and exploring How Stuff Works?  Fine, whatever.  Needs to work on someone else's machine?  Hell No.  Just call c_str().  An optimized build will likely inline c_str() anyway.  The only rational reason I can come up with for wanting to do this is 'efficiency', and this won't help you at all.  The only thing it does is ties you to a particular implementation in a particular version of The Standard Library.  Unless you're basically tearing apart your toaster to see how it works, just call c_str().  Please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a matter of implementation. Let's assume you are using libstdc++. Then, the first member of `std::string` is [a pointer to the stored string (char array)](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/basic_string.h#L166). Which is what you get.

Since SSO is applied for your short string, this pointer points to a [buffer inside the `std::string` object itself, located at its offset 16](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/basic_string.h#L173) (`b0 - a0` in hex).

For example, if we look at the libstdc++ implementation :

```
_Alloc_hider _M_dataplus;  // offset 0 - an address of object - pointer to data
size_type    _M_string_length;

enum { _S_local_capacity = 15 / sizeof(_CharT) };

union
{
  _CharT     _M_local_buf[_S_local_capacity + 1];  // offset 16 - short string stored here
  size_type  _M_allocated_capacity;
};
```

Where the pointer is stored inside `_Alloc_hider`:

```
pointer _M_p; // The actual data.
```

---

Note that your code may not work this (undefined) way with other implementations than the showed one. For example, libc++ uses another approach to the application of SSO. Generally, your code will <s>likely</s> result in **undefined behavior**, as others pointed out in comments.

Comment: Pedantic note, undefined behavior is a property that does not depend on the implementation. The behavior you will actually observe is what does. So this code has undefined behavior **even if** the particular implementation will give consistent and reliable behavior. In other words, a piece of code has or doesn't have undefined behavior, and how that undefined behavior acts in practice can vary from platform to platform, implementation to implementation and compiler to compiler. But even if a combination gives consistent results, the code itself still is undefined behavior.

Comment: Part 2 : Undefined Behavior means "The Standard doesn't have anything to say about the resulting behavior" which is true even if a given standard library implementation causes the code to behave reliably.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Are you sure? I believe UB does depend on the code. If you merge the OP's code with the code I showed (that exact implementation in libstdc++), why should it result in UB? That behavior is defined by the standard (dereferencing a pointer to the object of a standard-layout class as a pointer to its first member variable).

Comment: If you copy the code in it will work fine. But, the standard library is special. Unless you control it exactly, it's external to your code. So relying on it's structure is not allowed. If someone else takes the code and tries to compile it, it might not work the same way as you though. That's a property of Undefined Behavior. It might work for you but not the next person. You don't know how they will compile it. If you copy the string implementation into your project, rename it and use it instead of `std::string` then it would be okay (not great, but legal). It compiles the same for everyone.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux You're right, agree. I guess an implementation may for instance use a different version of `std::basic_string` definition each time I compile a program. Likely won't but can.

Comment: *Generally, your code will likely result in undefined behavior.* This is not true.  The code will **always** have UB as casting to a `char**` breaks strict aliasing.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Anyway, I was just trying to explain the (undefined) behavior OP is observing. Which, I believe, was the point of the question.

Comment: @NathanOliver Nice catch. I was just seeing `char*`.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> char * pExplicitlyConvertedString = *((char **)pPointerToStringObject);
> ```

That is not right and your program has undefined behavior when you dereference `pExplicitlyConvertedString`.

The standard-supported method would be to use [`std::string::data()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data).

```
char* s = TestString.data();
```

Comment: I do understand that this is not good practice at all. As I mentioned in my question I am just trying to gather some insight into the std::string implementation.

Comment: @Gavi When you are expermimenting with code that is subject to undefined behavior, the only way to make any sense of the behavior of the program is to look at the specific implementation of the standard library and ,many times, the assembly code generated by the compiler. It is hard to make the case for the behavior of the program from a platform agnostic point of view.

Comment: @DanielLangr, there no UB if something is implemented as you think. Maybe.
Compiler can do weird things if it can catch an UB. Have a look at (this)[https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140627-00/?p=633]