# How do i read a std::string from memory using RPM

Tags: c++, winapi, memory, stdstring

Okay, so recently i've been working witth RPM(ReadProccesMemory). But while doing so i bumped into the issue of not being able to read a string the way i wanted it.

This is what i heard/know:
I know, when reading a std::string, i get the memory adress of the string OBJECT and not the adress that contains the actual text.I am also aware of "Small String Optimization", and what it does in theory.

I'd like to be able to read the contents of varString(DefaultString) without changing the code of my dummy program(if possible).

The dummy program im reading:

```cpp
int main() {
    // Variables & Pointers
    int varInt = 123456;
    string varString = "DefaultString";
    cout << sizeof(varString);
    char arrChar[128] = { "Long char array right there ->" };
    int* ptr2int = &varInt;
    int** ptr2ptr = &ptr2int;
    int*** ptr2ptr2 = &ptr2ptr;

    // Printing them out
    while (true){
    cout << "Process ID: " << GetCurrentProcessId() << endl << endl;
    cout << "varInt (0x" << &varInt << ") = " << varInt << endl;
    cout << "varString (" << reinterpret_cast<const void*>(varString.data()) << ") = " << varString << endl;
    cout << "arrChar (0x" << &arrChar << ") = " << arrChar << endl << endl;

    cout << "ptr2int (0x" << &ptr2int << ") = " << &varInt << endl;
    cout << "ptr2ptr (0x" << &ptr2ptr << ") = " << &ptr2int << endl;
    cout << "ptr2ptr2 (0x" << &ptr2ptr2 << ") = " << &ptr2ptr << endl << endl;
    break;
    }

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

What im currently doing(wont work as intended):

```cpp
void reading_string(HANDLE handle_procces) {
    uintptr_t memoryAdress_2 = 0x0;
    cout << "Please write down the memory adress of \"varString\" > " << flush;
    cin >> hex >> memoryAdress_2;

    string read_string_object;
    ReadProcessMemory(handle_procces, (LPCVOID)memoryAdress_2, &read_string_object, sizeof(string), NULL);
    cout << "The value of this memory adress is: " << read_string_object << endl;
}
```

Comment: Somewhere inside the `std::string` there should be a pointer to the actual data. However, the memory layout of `std::string` is not standardized so that pointer could be anywhere. And that location could change from process to process, depending on what `std::string` was used.

Comment: This is pretty similar to the question [Explicit conversion from std::string object to char* without using any of std::string member functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57876214/explicit-conversion-from-stdstring-object-to-char-without-using-any-of-stds) from yesterday.

Comment: "Somewhere inside the std::string there should be a pointer to the actual data." How do i find that pointer? By manually searching for it or?

Comment: Do you need the pointer or what the pointer is pointing to?  See [std::string::data()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data), for a function that returns a pointer to the data.

Comment: @Jowen Usually you don't use it. You use the class interface and use the appropriate member function (for example `std::string::data()`). But since you are accessing another process' data, there isn't a easy built-in way of doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

std::string is a container, offset 0x14 is the size of the char array which it manages.  If the string is less than 15 characters, the second variable (offset 0x4 or 0x8 depending on x86/x64) is the char array itself.  If it's more than 15 characters, this variable turns into a pointer to the char array which is allocated dynamically

We can use this information to read the string externally, it's a hack but it works

Here some sample code which shows you how it's done:

```cpp
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void ReadExternalString(HANDLE hProc, uintptr_t addr, char* dstArray)
{
    //Get the size of the array, offset 0x14 is the size of the array

    //it's 0x14 on x86
    uintptr_t sizeoffset = 0x14;

    //check if x64
    if (sizeof(int*) == 8)
    {
        //assign correct offset
        sizeoffset = 0x18;
    }

    uintptr_t arraySize;

    ReadProcessMemory(hProc, (BYTE*)(addr + sizeoffset), &arraySize, sizeof(arraySize), 0);

    if (arraySize > 15)
    {
        uintptr_t addrOfCharArray;
        //dereference the pointer in the second member variable to get the dynamic address of the array
        ReadProcessMemory(hProc, (BYTE*)(addr + sizeof(void*)), &addrOfCharArray, sizeof(void*), 0);

        char buffer[500];
        //Read the array into buffer, +1 to get the null terminator
        ReadProcessMemory(hProc, (BYTE*)(addrOfCharArray), &buffer, arraySize + 1, 0);

        //copy the buffer into our ouput argument
        memcpy(dstArray, &buffer, strlen(buffer) + 1);
    }
    else
    {
        ReadProcessMemory(hProc, (BYTE*)(addr + sizeof(void*)), dstArray, arraySize, 0);
    }
}

std::string ourStringToRead = "Yolo";

int main()
{
    HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_VM_READ, FALSE, GetCurrentProcessId());

    if (hProcess == NULL)
    {
        cout << "OpenProcess failed. GetLastError = " << dec << GetLastError() << endl;
        system("pause");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    char* cString = new char[500];
    ZeroMemory(cString, 500);

    ReadExternalString(hProcess, (uintptr_t)&ourStringToRead, cString);

    cout << "string char array = " << cString << endl;
    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I know it's late but this code actually just printed junk to the console. I really want to know how to retrieve a std::string from it's "Object" address. any help on printing the actual string?

Comment: @LouaiKelani I just updated this answer and made this PoC simpler to use, just run it as admin and it'll work fine.

Comment: it worked on x86 but didn't on x64

Comment: @LouaiKelani I added x64 support

Comment: it worked thank you so much you need to mention the OP to mark this as answer. Believe me it's the only one in the whole internet.